# Is it actually possible to change <h2> div "group"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tumblr

The problem is that I already have caption for image, but another caption is appearing when I post from tumblr's mobile app. How can I "teleport" `<h2>` to `.innertitle`?

```
/* begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false */
```

**css:**

```
.innertitle {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          height: 15%;
          font-size: 1.5vw;
          font-family: sans-serif;
                }

    .contentbox {
          width: 40%;
          background: #ccc;
          position: relative;
          height: auto;
                }

    .img-around img {
          margin-top: 50px;
          width: 100%;
    }
```

**html:**

```
<div {block:Tags}id="{Tag}"{/block:Tags} class="contentbox">
                    <div class="innertitle">
                        {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
                    </div>
                    <div class="innerbox">
                        <div class="img-around">
                            <img src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/1efb53fff593aeb137b3c9b7b018a708/tumblr_pgggijEb4G1x36lvho1_1280.png">
                        <h2>This is appearing automatically.</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Hi Paul, your question is a bit unclear to me. What do you mean post from your phone? Can you explain or add a bit more detail?

Comment: You need to clarify what exactly the problem is and what exactly your desired results are. Your question is unclear. You also need to explain what you mean by an `<h2>` div "group" since that isn't a "thing".

Comment: Tumblr has mobile app. So when I post from pc it goes to <div class="innertitle"></div>. But when I post from Tumblr's mobile app it goes under the image with no reason. So i need to teleport this <h2> that is under the image to <div class="innertitle">here</div> somehow.

Comment: solved. caprion was in the wrong block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for that post, it was a long time ago, I knew English very badly.

For the future, who is interested in how to solve this, what I've done is I posted posts of every kind from Tumblr's mobile app and from website. Then I opened DevTools and looked how do posts posted from mobile app and website differ.
The problem was that Tumblr for some reason puts the p, h1, h2 tags of posts differently than in the mobile app. So I just needed to style both of them.
Again sorry for that post.